# How to configure ajax request with jquery in django?

Tags: python, jquery, django, ajax, django-csrf

So I was doing a django project by following a youtube video. And I got this error:

```
"Forbidden (403) CSRF verification failed. Request aborted."
```

everytime when I submit any  data in my sign-up.html file.
Then I realize I did not configure ajax correctly. So I search online and saw the django documentation of ajax. I made some changes in my html code. still, it did not solve my problem.
I am still getting the same result. What is my mistake here. Did I made any mistake while configuring ajax?

"assets/js/django-ajax.js" 
This is where i save the jquery file.

Its been a while since I am stuck in this problem.

Thank you for your time

My sign-up.html file:

```
 {% load static %}
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Instapic</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'assets/css/Login-Form-Clean.css' %}">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'assets/css/styles.css' %}">
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="login-clean">
            <form method="post">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <h2 class="sr-only">Login Form</h2>
                <div class="illustration">
                        <div style="display: none" id="errors" class="well form-error-message"></div>
                        <img src="{% static 'assets/img/logo.jpg' %}">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input class="form-control" id="username" type="text" name="username" required="" placeholder="Username" maxlength="20" minlength="4">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input class="form-control" id="email" type="email" name="email" required="" placeholder="Email" maxlength="100" minlength="6">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input class="form-control" id="password" type="password" name="password" required="" placeholder="Password" maxlength="20" minlength="6">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" id="go" type="submit">Create Account</button>
                </div><a href="#" class="forgot">Already got an account? Login here ...</a></form>
        </div>
        <script src="{% static 'assets/js/jquery.min.js' %}"></script>
        <script src="{% static 'assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
        <script src="{% static 'assets/js/django-ajax.js' %}"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#go').click(function() {
            $.post("ajax-sign-up",
        {
            username: $("#username").val(),
            email: $("#email").val(),
            password: $("#password").val()
        },
        function(data, status){
        if (JSON.parse(data).Status == 'Success') {
            window.location = '/';
        } else {
            $('#errors').html("<span>" + JSON.parse(data).Message + "</span>")
            $('#errors').css('display', 'block')
        }
        });
            return false;
            })
    })
        </script>
    </body>

    </html>
```

My ajax configureation:

```
    // using jQuery
    function getCookie(name) {
        var cookieValue = null;
        if (document.cookie && document.cookie != '') {
            var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
            for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
                var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
                // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
                if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) == (name + '=')) {
                    cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return cookieValue;
    }
    var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');

    function sameOrigin(url) {
        // test that a given url is a same-origin URL
        // url could be relative or scheme relative or absolute
        var host = document.location.host; // host + port
        var protocol = document.location.protocol;
        var sr_origin = '//' + host;
        var origin = protocol + sr_origin;
        // Allow absolute or scheme relative URLs to same origin
        return (url == origin || url.slice(0, origin.length + 1) == origin + '/') ||
            (url == sr_origin || url.slice(0, sr_origin.length + 1) == sr_origin + '/') ||
            // or any other URL that isn't scheme relative or absolute i.e relative.
            !(/^(\/\/|http:|https:).*/.test(url));
    }
    function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
        // these HTTP methods do not require CSRF protection
        return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
    }
    $.ajaxSetup({
        beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
            if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: When you click the button the page refreshes with the message or you can see the response in your browser's dev tools?

Comment: the page refreshs with the message

Answer (score 0):

Your click handler does not prevent the event from propagating. When your event handler has run the event will propagate and will eventually submit the form as a regular browser POST. You need to prevent this from happening

```
$('#go').click(function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
```

Comment: i change the code like this:   $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#go').click(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
        $.post("ajax-sign-up",
    {
        username: $("#username").val(),
        email: $("#email").val(),
        password: $("#password").val()
    },    still having the same problem

Comment: Sorry, it's stopPropagation in jquery

Comment: what should i do now?\

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest, add your csrf_token in every ajax.post for test, to be sure that generated token in cookies is correct.

Example:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "",
    data: {
        username: $("#username").val(),
        email: $("#email").val(),
        password: $("#password").val(),
        'csrfmiddlewaretoken': getCookie('csrftoken')
    }
})
```

In your code. you defined method getCookie in JS, create variable csrf_token and implement this variable in ajaxSetup. Well, token is changing, but your script does not reload it.

If you want to use ajax.setup, put inside there the method getCookie, to be sure that ajax before send *retakes correct* token.